# matplotlib sharex across multiple figures

Tags: matplotlib

I am able to use sharex across subplots. However, I am not able to use sharex across mulitple figures.

For example, I want to create:

(1) 1st figure, 3 X 2 = 6 subplots

(2) 2nd figure, 3 X 2 = 6 subplots.

When I zoom in onto 1 of the 12 subplots, I want all 12 subplots to zoom into the same x range. I attempted the code below, but am unable to get it to work. it seems that "ax1" is not a valid input for sharex. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1, ((ax1,ax2), (ax3,ax4), (ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(3,2, sharex = True)
fig2, ((ax11,ax21), (ax31,ax41), (ax51, ax61)) = plt.subplots(3,2, sharex = ax1)
```

Comment: You cannot share across figures. You could try with subfigures.  If you really need to share across figures, you will probably have to set up draw-time callbacks.

Comment: Yes. I really need to share across multiple plots which maybe up to 48 plots for example. Coming from a Matlab background, it was quite easily achievable on Matlab. I will read up on all those you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After some struggling, realized that the bottom code will work. But not sure whether it is the most optimized way. When one of the plot is zoomed in, all the rest follows, which is what is needed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1.fig.add_subplot(3,2,1)
ax2.fig.add_subplot(3,2,2, sharex = ax1)
ax3.fig.add_subplot(3,2,3, sharex = ax1)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax4.fig2.add_subplot(3,2,1, sharex = ax1)
ax5.fig2.add_subplot(3,2,2, sharex = ax1)
ax6.fig2.add_subplot(3,2,3, sharex = ax1)
```